# How to add User to LDAP Groups in PDI?

Tags: ldap, pdi

How to add users to LDAP Groups using PDI tool with the help of component "LDAP Output"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to input steps: One to read the users and one to read the groups. How you join these two step depends on the LDAP server you use.

You can either join:

- through the memberof attribute of the user. This is what ActiveDirectory does.
- or by the member attribute of the group. This is what most Unix-based diretory servers do,

In either case the attribute contains the distinguished name of the other entity (e.g. memberOf refers to the DN of group he is a memeber of).